# Unsupported option error in ZAP Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, owasp, zap

I am new to ZAP OWASP. I am trying to set up Jenkins job which runs on Windows slave machine.
I am getting attached error on windows slave machine.[image]

How can I fix the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are somehow passing those parameters to ZAP as one blob. ZAP expects then as separate parameters. Why thats happenning I dont know, but it will be related to the way you are launching ZAP.

Comment: I followed the document - https://www.we45.com/blog/how-to-integrate-zap-into-jenkins-ci-pipeline-we45-blog

Comment: Be that as it may, ZAP is getting them as one combined parameter, which isnt going to work. Unfortunately the Jenkins plugin is no longer supported by the ZAP team.

Comment: I have downloaded Cross platform package and placed in C:\ProgramFiles\. i tried to start zap daemon from command prompt using zap.bat -daemon -host localhost -port 8080 i get the same error like attached above with only parameters unsupported option : -daemon -host localhost -port 8080

Comment: Can you post the exact command you are using - it works fine for me :/

Comment: also i am using 2.9.0 version

Comment: Thats really strange - that should work fine, and I've just sanity checked it on my Windows box and it works for me :/ Do other command line tools work ok when you pass multiple arguments to them?

Comment: I tried sending same commands on unix machine (ubuntu) , "4724 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing The Online menu links
4724 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader  - Initializing Allows to fuzz WebSocket messages.
4923 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.callback.ExtensionCallback  - Started callback server on 0.0.0.0:38891
5176 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.DaemonBootstrap  - ZAP is now listening on  localhost:8090". Daemon was started and zap was listening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222034/discussion-between-ashu123-and-simon-bennetts).